# How to center a table with validation error column

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to center this table without taking into account the third column, which is for data validation. I have it rendering exactly how I want it now with the display none attributes on the third column but then my error text won't show. What is the simplest way to go about this? Thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="budgetTracker.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/custom.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container center">
            <div class="center">
                <div class="vert">

                    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <h1>Budget Tracker Login</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="userNamelbl" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="userNameBox" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            <td style="display: none;">
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="userNameRequired" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username is Required" ControlToValidate="userNameBox" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="passwordlbl" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="passwordBox" class="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            <td style="display: none;">
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="passwordRequired" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password is Required" ControlToValidate="passwordBox" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-space" Text="Login" OnClick="loginButton_Click" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">Not yet a member? Click <a href="Register.aspx">HERE</a> to register!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are designed to display tabular data, not to build a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marco is right, table should be used for tabular data not for layout.

To answer your question, you can remove the `"display: none;"` in your td tag.

Add a label control for your error message (I'd call it "ErrorLabel") then add this code on in your "error area" (that would be inside your loginButton_Click method)

```
ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
```

In your PageLoad, add this:

```
if (!IsPostBack){
   ErrorLabel.Visible = false;
}
```